# Add image URL automatically to custom field?

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, images, post-thumbnails

Does anyone know how I automatically add the URL of the uploaded image to a custom field?

In other words, When I upload a image I want the url to the image to get a custom field variable automatically so I dont have to add the URL manually to the custom field all the time.

I need a seamless integration to make is user-friendly. I want to use scripts like timthumb instead of the built in WP functionality.

**-----UPDATE:**

Here is some code I have. Just missing the thumbnail variable in the custom value field.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'mk_set_default_custom_fields');

function mk_set_default_custom_fields($post_id)
{
    if ( $_GET['post_type'] != 'post' ) {

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image', 'I WANT THE THUMBNAIL HERE', true);

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_meta_Function_Examples ? where is the image url coming from?

Comment: The image-url is the first image in the post. i.e. the thumbnail

Comment: Why would you not want to use WP thumbnail functionality? You're placing more load on your server per page view using TimThumb.

Comment: Because I'm using Wordpress Multiuser with sitewide tagss. I want to show user images in the loop by using custom fields, and I got that ufnctioon working. Now I'm trying to make it more userfriendly by automating the timthumb-image-link. So I really need this one to customie my front page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code that adds the thumbnail url to a custom field named Image.

```
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
        return $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    } else {
        return '';  // or a default thumbnail url
    }
}


add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically', 'w_thumbnail_src');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_id) {
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Image', w_thumbnail_src(), true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to store the URL in a custom field, the thumbnail id is already stored in a custom field under the key `_thumbnail_id`. You can fetch the ID via [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to get the URL.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress Multiuser with sitewide tags. I want to show user images in the loop by using custom fields, and I got that function working. Now I'm trying to make it more userfriendly by automating the timthumb-image-link. So I really need this one to customie my front page. I have tried what you describe but cant get it working with my setup. So the easyes and most userfriendly is if I could add the first uploaded image on a post automaticly to a custom field by pressing a button or something in the ipload-menu

Comment: Show us the code you tried and we'll help you get it working, as I'm sure you'll agree requiring your users do nothing is the most user-friendly.

Comment: ok, I hva updated the post with the code I got. Can you take a look at it? :)

Comment: I meant the code you tried regarding my original answer for just fetching the thumbnail from existing meta, not adding the URL to a custom field. again, that will be far easier than what you're trying to do here, as you'll have to check that the thumbnail hasn't changed every time the post is updated.

Comment: I'm no pro in PHP, so I cant see where you are going. I need the URL in the custom field because I use multisite with sitewide tags. So I do a import of all blogs with custom fields to show all posts on my main blog..

Comment: this plugin is soooooo close! Just not adding it automaticly http://www.mikevanwinkle.com/wordpress/attachments-as-post-custom-fields